# Overwriting Super Variables Java

Tags: java

I have a class `Client`, which has a variable `privilege` which I cannot edit. I can however edit a class `Launcher` which extends `Client`. A method in `Client` checks the privilege, and I would like to overwrite the `privilege` variable before that method.

```
public class Client { // I can't edit this class at all

    private int privilege = 0;

    public void chat(String msg) {
        if (privilege == 3) {
            // send chat packet with privileges to server
        }
    }
}
```

Then in a seperate file:

```
public class Launcher extends Client { // I can edit this class
    // This is what I tried... it didn't work
    @Override
    public void chat(String msg) {
        int privilege = 3;
        super.chat(msg);
    }
}
```

This is part of a game I've decompiled, and I'd like to overwrite the privilege variable (cheat), how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Once you learn what it means for a variable to be private, you will understand that what you are trying to accomplish is not possible

Comment: If you're already decompiling the game, why *not* edit `Client`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no solution

Comment: Yeah, I know what private variables are, I thought the community might have a workaround for this.

Comment: @user2357112 The decompiler I used created an incorrect Java file, I can't recompile it so I can't use it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there isn't a way, I'll delete the question... nevermind I can't

Comment: The point of the `private` keyword is that no one - including subclasses - besides the class itself can access those members. So no, there is no workaround. You'd have to modify the parent class or create and use a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to write `private` fields. Get the [field,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-) make it [accessible,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject:A-boolean-) and [assign](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#setInt-java.lang.Object-int-) the value you want. A similar approach can be used to invoke private methods.

```
@Override
public void chat(String msg)
{
  try {
    Field field = Client.class.getDeclaredField("privilege");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.setInt(this, 3);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to modify field", ex);
  }
  super.chat(msg);
}
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks.

Comment: The reflection access modification seems incredibly unsafe (overall not in this specific example). Isn't the point of java's access modifiers to make variables safe in polymorphism?

Comment: @EliSadoff Access modification is a privileged action, and the runtime can be configured to deny its use by untrusted code.

Comment: @erickson Ah, I didn't realize it was a privileged action; however, I guess I could have inferred that from the `RuntimeException` being thrown.